# Why the condition of my *ngIf is ignored with Observable

Tags: angular, ngxs

Here is my main component.

```html
<div *ngIf="user$ | async">
  <h1>test</h1>
</div>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-core',
  templateUrl: './core.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./core.component.scss']
})
export class CoreComponent {
  @Select(UserState) public user$!: Observable<User>;
  constructor() {}
}
```

And I wrote UserState, with ngxs.

```
@State<UserStateModel>({
  name: 'user',
})
@Injectable()
export class UserState {
  constructor(
    private api: ApiService,
    private tokens: TokenService) { }

  @Action(GetUser)
  public get(ctx: StateContext<UserStateModel>) {
    const id = this.tokens.getAccessTokenPayload()!.sub;
    return this.api.get<User>(Endpoint.USERS, id).pipe(
      tap((user: User) => {
        ctx.setState(user);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Why the condition of my *ngIf is ignored and the router-outlet is rendered when I haven't even initialized the value of my user state.

*With ReduxDevtool*

[image: With Redux Devtool]

## Update after Michaël answer

```html
<div *ngIf="user">
  <h1>test</h1>
</div>
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-core',
  templateUrl: './core.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./core.component.scss']
})
export class CoreComponent implements OnInit {
  public user?: User;
  constructor() {}
  public ngOnInit(){
    this.store.select(UserState).subscribe((user) => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }
}
```

For testing purposes, I tried this, and the user state is still initialized. I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you please refer below answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49631742/ngif-not-working-as-expected-with-observable

Comment: @Dakopatel They talk about adding parentheses to encapsulate asynchrony, but my problem seems to come from something else. (I've updated my answer)

Comment: Can you try once with [ngIf] instead of *ngIf.

Comment: It does not work. If I push a user into my user state, it's never rendering

Comment: Ohh ! i see.....

Comment: Your data (empty object) is actually true’ish. That is why it is rendering.

Comment: @MikeOne Is there any way that there is no default value? Rather than being forced to subscribe to the Observable

Comment: In your original solution, just take a property inside your user to check for, something like *ngIf= “(user$ | async)?.name” (if name exists there)

Answer (score 0):

According to [NGXS documentation](https://www.ngxs.io/concepts/select) :

> By adding the definite assignment assertion we're telling the
> type-checker that we're sure that pandas$ property will be initialized
> (by the @Select decorator).

So the fact you are using both @Select AND [Definite Assignment Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) causes your user$ to be initialized.

Comment: I tried some change (I update my question above), and the user state is still initialized. I don't understand why.